IIS V10.0 'ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND'
I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out, we have an ASP.NET project using MVC that runs on each of our computers using IIS for development purposes and has been working just fine up until recently. I got an error to do with IIS (Cant remember exactly what error but it was a minor issue) and followed the troubleshooting guide from Microsoft for IIS.
It tells me to enable a feature which I do then asks to restart the computer which I also do, after booting, IIS is gone. I had to reinstall it using the CMD because it wasn't even an option in the enable features menu.
Thankfully I had the config files backed up but now after going through the setup and configuration again, I'm met with:
Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
So I check the event viewer and find this error message from the DefaultAppPool:
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
Ok, fair enough maybe not all the modules got installed when I reinstalled IIS from the CMD, no problem, I go into the enable features menu and enable all the necessary modules.
This changes absolutely nothing. Both errors are still present and we're losing productivity because IIS is being stupid.
I've double checked literally every config in IIS and followed every guide I could find on this website, still nothing. Its just baffling, if it at least told me what module was missing this wouldn't have been an issue.
Edit: Heres the event that pops up in event viewer
System 

- Provider 

[ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WAS 
[ Guid]  {524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40} 
[ EventSourceName]  WAS 
 
- EventID 5139 

[ Qualifiers]  32768 
 
Version 0 
 
Level 3 
 
Task 0 
 
Opcode 0 
 
Keywords 0x80000000000000 
 
- TimeCreated 

[ SystemTime]  2024-04-18T09:47:40.4387252Z 
 
EventRecordID 805979 
 
Correlation 
 
- Execution 

[ ProcessID]  0 
[ ThreadID]  0 
 
Channel System 
 
Computer DEV02
 
Security 
 
- EventData 
AppPoolID DefaultAppPool 
ProcessID 12680 
param3 0 
ProtocolID http 
7E000780 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:

In Words
0000: 8007007E    

In Bytes
0000: 7E 00 07 80  


First, you will have to show the entire log entry from Event Viewer, as it has a Details tab. Second a tool like Process Monitor can show more visually which files w3wp.exe fails to find.

Are using some plugins or DLLs with MVC App? Either the DLLs you are loading, or one of its dependencies, cannot be found. Perhaps you failed to install the necessary dependencies, e.g. the runtime. Or perhaps it is something else. You'll need to do some debugging and investigation. I would start by profiling the DLL load using Dependency Walker.

@Lex Li I used Event Viewer in the hopes of getting more detailed logs but all they specify is the error code when the app pool crashes.
I'll add the crash event to my post

@Chinmay T Not that I'm aware of, I only inherited this project as is a month ago but I'll take a look once I figure out how dependency walker works

Try using failed request tracing to see details about 503 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
